# Google Font "Playfair Display" rendering issue with two "ff" letters

Tags: javascript, debugging, font-face

I've noticed an issue with the Google Font "Playfair Display" when two "f" characters are right next to each other.

[example of strange rendering issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXu0O.png)

The best solution I can think of is writing a javascript function to search across all the text on the site for "ff" and wrapping the first character in a span, which fixes the issue.

```
function deEffer() {
    var text = $("body:first").html();
    text = text.replace("ff", "<span>f</span>f");
    $("body:first").html(text);
}
```

Curious to if anybody has a more graceful solution.

Thanks!

Comment: That's intentional. That's the way the font is supposed to look. Such pairings of characters are called "kerning pairs" or "ligatures". See what "fi" looks like. Look through some old books and you'll see lots of stuff like that.

Comment: [A bit more info here](http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/ligature/) and [here](http://ilovetypography.com/2007/09/09/decline-and-fall-of-the-ligature/).

Comment: You could alter the font and remove the ligature using font forge

Comment: @MathiasW that's true but if one goes to the trouble of choosing a font because its appearance, tone, weight, and emotive content are pleasing, you're implicitly acknowledging the skill of the font designer. Font design is hard. To just go in and willy-nilly un-do important parts of the design is like buying a painting and cutting out the part with the type of dog you don't like.

Comment: Yes indeed @Pointy, can't argue with that.

Comment: That is interesting and good to know @Pointy! I was proactively looking to fix it because I'm pretty sure the design team is going to yell at me for it being an bug. Now I can drop some design knowledge on their faces ;-P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CSS allows you to select the font variation. `font-variant-ligatures` is what you're looking for. And [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures) are great.

I think this is what you're looking for specifically.

```
font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
```

While it's certainly how the typeface was designed, not every use calls for them.